# Small Inequality question

Tags: inequality

I am unable to understand an inequality in a solution which says  $ (1-\frac{1}{e})>\frac{1}{4}(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}})$

I  know  $ \frac{1}{e}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$ ,

hence  $ (1-\frac{1}{e})<(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}})$

Thanks.

Comment: Use $(1-\frac1e) = (1-\frac1{\sqrt e})(1+\frac1{\sqrt e})$.